# Merge sort algorithm using recursion

Tags: ruby, recursion, mergesort

I'm doing The Odin Project. The practice problem is: create a merge sort algorithm using recursion. The following is modified from someone's solution:

```
def merge_sort(arry)
  # kick out the odds or kick out of the recursive splitting?
  # I wasn't able to get the recombination to work within the same method.
  return arry if arry.length == 1
  arry1 = merge_sort(arry[0...arry.length/2])
  arry2 = merge_sort(arry[arry.length/2..-1])
  f_arry = []
  index1 = 0 # placekeeper for iterating through arry1
  index2 = 0 # placekeeper for iterating through arry2
  # stops when f_arry is as long as combined subarrays
  while f_arry.length < (arry1.length + arry2.length)
    if index1 == arry1.length
      # pushes remainder of arry2 to f_arry
      # not sure why it needs to be flatten(ed)!
      (f_arry << arry2[index2..-1]).flatten!
    elsif index2 == arry2.length
      (f_arry << arry1[index1..-1]).flatten!
    elsif arry1[index1] <= arry2[index2]
      f_arry << arry1[index1]
      index1 += 1
    else
      f_arry << arry2 [index2]
      index2 += 1
    end
  end
  return f_arry
end
```

1. Is the first line `return arry if arry.length == 1` kicking it out of the recursive splitting of the array(s) and then bypassing the recursive splitting part of the method to go back to the recombination section? It seems like it should then just keep resplitting it once it gets back to that section as it recurses through.
2. Why must it be `flatten`-ed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to understand the first line is to understand that the only contract that `merge_sort` is bound to is to "return a sorted array" - if the array has only one element (`arry.length == 1`) it is *already sorted* - so nothing needs to be done! Simply return the array itself.

In recursion, this is known as a "Stop condition". If you don't provide a stop condition - the recursion will never end (since it will always call itself - and never return)!

The result you need to `flatten` your result, is because you are pushing an array as an element in you resulting array:

```
arr = [1]
arr << [2, 3]
# => [1, [2, 3]]
```

If you try to flatten the resulting array only at the end of the iteration, and not as you are adding the elements, you'll have a problem, since its *length* will be skewed:

```
arr = [1, [2, 3]]
arr.length
# => 2
```

Although `arr` contains three *numbers* it has only *two elements* - and that will break your solution.

You want all the elements in your array to be *numbers*, not arrays. [`flatten!`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-flatten-21) makes sure that all elements in your array are atoms, and if they are not, it adds the child array's elements to itself instead of the child array:

```
arr.flatten!
# => [1, 2, 3]
```

Another you option you might want to consider (and will be more efficient) is to use [`concat`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-concat) instead:

```
arr = [1]
arr.concat([2, 3])
# => [1, 2, 3]
```

This method add all the elements in the array passed as parameter to the array it is called on.

Comment: Here's what I'm having issues with in that:

Comment: @spectre6000 - where?

Comment: Assume a passed in array of [1,2,3,4]

Walking through as I understand it:

Drill down through the recursion until you have 4 one-number arrays. The if statement catches it and returns the four one number arrays; they're already sorted, so that's the stop condition. Got that part.

I get lost about a step or so out from that. The bottom step then recombines the single arrays into two sets of two, but the next then has to recombine those two... SORTED sets!

Click. 

I get why and that it needs to be .flatten(ed)!, what I don't quite understand is why it needs to be at that exact location...

Comment: Accidentally submitted that first response, then took too long to edit it... Sorry.

Comment: Concat is also much cleaner and prettier. Thanks for that too!

Comment: @spectre6000 - you need to `flatten!` where you do, since you use the `length` of your array in the algorithm, and that won't be correct until you make sure it is flattened. As for how you combine two sorted sets to a single sorted set - that is _the heart_ of the merge sort - you can read more about it here - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort

Comment: The confusion with why it needs to be .flatten(ed)! in that location is because it works in some instances if the final returned f_array is .flatten(ed)! as well... I'm going to have to run through it in my mind in the same way I just did to see if that clicks in a similar fashion.
-
In another related train, how deep does the recursion rabbit hole often get in the wild?

Comment: @spectre6000 - I've edited the answer with an explanation about the relationship between `length` and `flatten`

Comment: @spectre6000 - I'm not sure what you mean with "recursion rabbit hole" - are you talking about how prevalent it is? the answer is very... there are technologies where this is the preferred method to solve problems (http://learnyousomeerlang.com/recursion), and others where you need to be careful not to overuse it, since it might have memory overhead, and might also explode if used incorrectly.